# How to access data outside the function using axios and react js

Tags: reactjs, axios

when call the retriveStudentPhoto() function from h1 tag . I can't get the value return .How do I solve this.
Thanks in advance .

```
                               {data.map((val, index) => (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style={{ outline: 'none' }} data-heading="Photo">
                                          <h1{ retriveStudentPhoto(val.email) }</h1> /*call 
                                                                                             this function */ 
                                        </td>
                               ))}
```

```
   function retriveStudentPhoto (email)  {
          var photo = ""
          axios.get(`/user-info/${email}`)
          .then((result)=>{
          photo = result.data[0].profile_photo; 
        }).catch((error)=>error)
        return photo ;
     }
```

Since the function is inside the map , there will be call multiple times and the value will be returned each time. I used the useState hook but not getting results as per demand.

please help me more. Thanks in advance.

complete Code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import $ from 'jquery';
import axios from '../../config/axios';
import '../Attendance_Table/css/App.scss';
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function PeopleList({ match }) {
    const course_code = match.params.course_code;
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
    const [course_name, setcourse_name] = useState("");


    var breakOn = 'medium'
    let tableClass = 'table-container__table';
    if (breakOn === 'small') {
        tableClass += ' table-container__table--break-sm';
    } else if (breakOn === 'medium') {
        tableClass += ' table-container__table--break-md';
    } else if (breakOn === 'large') {
        tableClass += ' table-container__table--break-lg';
    }
    const headingColumns = ['Photo', 'Student ID', 'Name', 'Email']
    const headingColumns2 = ['Photo', 'Name', 'Email']
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [studentsPhoto, setStudentsPhoto] = useState([]);
    const [techInfo, setTechInfo] = useState([]);



    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/course/info/${course_code}`).then((result) => {
            setcourse_name(result.data[0].course_name)
        })

        SearchHandle();


    }, [])
    let SearchHandle = () => {

        axios.get(`people/${course_code}`).then((result) => {
            setData(result.data)

            // teacher info retrieve 
            axios.get(`user-info/${result.data[0].tecEmail}`)
                .then((res) => {

                    setTechInfo(res.data[0]);

                })
            //close teacher retrieve

            let student_photo = [];
            let promises = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                promises.push(

                    axios.get(`/user-info/${result.data[i].email}`)
                        .then((res) => {
                            student_photo.push(res?.data[0]?.profile_photo)
                        })

                )

            }
            Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                setStudentsPhoto(student_photo);
            })
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))


    }




    function retriveStudentPhoto(email) {
        var photo = "";
        axios.get(`/user-info/${email}`)
            .then((result) => {
                var photo = result.data[0].profile_photo;

            }).catch((error) => error)

        return photo;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {/* {msg ? ( */}
            <div>



                <div className="table-container" style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                    <div className="table-container__title">
                        <h5>People -- {course_name}({course_code})</h5>
                    </div>
                    <h5 style={{ padding: '10px', fontFamily: 'roboto' }}>Teacher</h5>
                    <table style={{ outline: 'none', border: 'none' }} className={tableClass}>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                {headingColumns2.map((col, index) => (
                                    <th data-heading={index} key={index}>{col}</th>

                                ))}

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>



                            <tr>
                                <td style={{ outline: 'none' }} data-heading="Photo">
                                    {techInfo.profile_photo ? (
                                        <img style={{ borderRadius: '150px', height: '40px', width: '40px' }}
                                            src={techInfo.profile_photo} />
                                    ) : (
                                        <img style={{ borderRadius: '150px', height: '40px', width: '40px' }}
                                            src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/s75-c-fbw=1/photo.jpg" />

                                    )}

                                </td>

                                <td data-heading="Student Name">{techInfo.name} </td>
                                <td data-heading="Student Email"><span style={{ fontSize: '11.5px' }}>{techInfo.email}</span> </td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table><br />




                    <br />
                    {data.length ? (
                        <table style={{ outline: 'none', border: 'none' }} className={tableClass}>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    {headingColumns.map((col, index) => (
                                        <th data-heading={index} key={index}>{col}</th>

                                    ))}

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                {data.map((val, index) => (
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style={{ outline: 'none' }} data-heading="Photo">

                                            <h1>{retriveStudentPhoto(val.email)}</h1>

                                        </td>
                                        <td style={{ outline: 'none' }} data-heading="Student ID">{val.student_id}</td>
                                        <td data-heading="Student Name">{val.student_name} </td>
                                        <td data-heading="Student Email"><span style={{ fontSize: '11.5px' }}>{val.email}</span> </td>

                                    </tr>
                                ))}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <Alert className="md-4 w-100"  variant="danger">
                                No Student add to this course yet
                            </Alert>
                        </div>
                    )}
                    <br />
                    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', paddingBottom: '5px' }}>
                        <Link to={`/attendance-sheet/${course_code}`}><span>Back to {course_code}</span></Link>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            {/* ) : ""} */}
        </div>

    );
}

export default PeopleList;
```

Comment: Please use state for store the response

Comment: Render is a pure, synchronous function. If you need to make asynchronous calls then do this in a lifecycle, in this case, a `useEffect` hook and store the results in state to be rendered. If you need further help with this then please edit question to include a complete code example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: as a better syntax you should use {retriveStudentPhoto(val.email)}

Comment: @Drew Reese, I have shared the complete code. please, kindly help me.

Comment: @krushnasinh jadeja, It would be nice if you could write the code with a little effort. I have tried many processes but not hutch. Please respond brother, it will be useful for me.

Comment: @Zafrulhasannasim did you remove the "var" inside the .then block in the retriveStudentPhoto ?

Comment: @DrewReese, I have shared the complete code. Please brother,  kindly help me more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render is a pure, synchronous function. If you need to make asynchronous calls then do this in a lifecycle, in this case, a `useEffect` hook and store the results in state to be rendered.

Iterate over the `result.data` array and issue the GET request, and when the request resolves issue a functional state update to create a new `data` array, using the iterated element's index to inject a new `photo` property.

```
const SearchHandle = () => {
  axios.get(`people/${course_code}`)
    .then((result) => {
      setData(result.data);

      result.data.forEach(async (item, index) => {
        try {
          const result = await axios.get(`/user-info/${item.email}`);
          const photo = result.data[0].profile_photo;
          setData(data => data.map(
            (el, i) => i === index
              ? { ...el, photo }
              : el)
          )
        } catch(error) {
          // log error, etc...
        }
      });

      ...

}
```

In the render access the new `photo` property you added above.

```
{data.map((val, index) => (
  <tr key={val.student_name}>
    <td style={{ outline: 'none' }} data-heading="Photo">
      <h1>{val.photo}</h1>
    </td>
    <td style={{ outline: 'none' }} data-heading="Student ID">{val.student_id}</td>
      <td data-heading="Student Name">{val.student_name} </td>
      <td data-heading="Student Email">
        <span style={{ fontSize: '11.5px' }}>{val.email}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
)}
```

Comment: I did as you instructed, a lot has happened but "{val.photo}  is continuously  returning, it looks like a lot of toggles.

Comment: @Zafrulhasannasim Ack, yeah, render looping. You could just move the photo fetching into the `SearchHandle` handler after the data's been fetched.

Comment: Please, rewrite the code would be very helpful for me. It would have been better for me to edit the code with a little patience. So far you have helped me a lot. I am hopeful, you will help me again

Comment: @Zafrulhasannasim I did update the code in my answer. Is that working or are you looking for something different?

Comment: Yeah brother,  absolutely done.   You are really gem.  Thanks a lot.  Jajakallahu khairan.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a function with async data in the render, so probably you dont have the data yet.
Try to keep the data from that axios.get in the state, youd probably want also to implement useEffect to make the call and store it to the state when component mounts

Comment: Please, help me kindly. write me the code would be advantage for me.